# How to pass data from state in Iframe and access the state values from other project(React.js)?

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I have to pass url params id to other project .I mounted the project to Iframe.So how can i pass the Id to Iframe and acsess that Id in other Project.Thanks in advance.

```js
import React from 'react'

function Insert() {

    return (
        <div> 
            <iframe src="http://localhost:3001" ID={"12345678"} style={{display:"block",width:"100%" ,height:"80vh"}}  ></iframe>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Insert
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the id value as a parameter in url?

```
import React from 'react'

function Insert() {

    return (
        <div> 
            <iframe src="http://localhost:3001/12345678" ID={"12345678"} style={{display:"block",width:"100%" ,height:"80vh"}}  ></iframe>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Insert
```

After this, in your parent file, you can get the value using `props`.